# Chrome scrolls up the page when I click on a link on a large image map

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

In Google Chrome browser, when I click on a link on a large image map, the page scrolls up as if the PhUp key were pressed.

When I test the page with Firefox and IE8, everything is fine.

Does anyone know anything about this problem with Chrome browser?

> example page: http://www.futerox.in/winksquare
>
> Please open the page in Chrome, scroll down and click on any image (not ad) on the image grid. You'll see that the whole page scrolls up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you aren't preventing the default click event handler. Couldn't determine where you hook up your image map. Try adding an evt.preventDefault() or a return false in your event handler for the image map.